# MySQL Cannot create EVENTs

Tags: mysql, events, xampp, mariadb

I'm trying to create an `EVENT` to fire up at schedule everyday to update data in table. I have set the `event_scheduler` ON in MySQL with `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` command, and this is what I see when I run the following:

```
MariaDB [hr]> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
| Id  | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State                    | Info             | Progress |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
|   1 | system user     |           | NULL | Daemon  |  NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   2 | system user     |           | NULL | Daemon  |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   3 | system user     |           | NULL | Daemon  |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   4 | system user     |           | NULL | Daemon  |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   5 | system user     |           | NULL | Daemon  |  NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 228 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL | Daemon  | 10486 | Waiting on empty queue   | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 613 | root            | localhost | hr   | Query   |     0 | Init                     | SHOW PROCESSLIST |    0.000 |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

So event_scheduler is indeed running. This is how I am creating the trigger:

```
CREATE EVENT update_attendance
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
  DO
    UPDATE attendance SET markedAttendance = 1;
```

When I run this, it says `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)`, but when I run `SHOW EVENTS` it returns an empty set. Also if I do DROP `update_attendance` it drops the event. The trigger is never executed even once. I am running XAMPP's MySQL on Windows 10. I do not understand what is going on. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i have a feeling you might need/want to add `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` as well..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I added it but it didn't make a difference. Same things from before. Would it even make a difference when the event never fired up?

Comment: *"Would it make a difference if it never even ran once?"* No it would not your question wasn't totally clear that the event never was executed once... Run a `SHOW WARNINGS;` directly after the `CREATE EVENT` maybe you get a hint why it is not working..

Comment: There are no warnings after I create the trigger.

Comment: The only reason i can think off why it might fail is that the UPDATE query is "wrong" meaning wrong table name or column name.. MySQL does not check the validation of the UPDATE during CREATE EVENT -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNzXscoFWmibr69BV31fPc/0    notice i can create events with missing "objects" (in this case a missing table)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have already double checked the query and it is executed fine from the command line. :/

Comment: *"I have already double checked the query and it is executed fine from the command line"* You didn't say it in the question, i had to ask and show to rule some things out..   Restarting the MySQL server/ PC did you also tryed that?   Besides that iam also out of ideas and have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: [MySQL Event does not run](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/mysql-event-does-not-run) it also might be a bug case..  Also notice the answer *"

I believe your event must be defined using fully qualified schema and tablename:"*  Which does make sense..

Comment: I did restart the PC and MySQL but it still doesn't work. I will look into this other thread as well.

Comment: Please do not use the term "trigger".  `EVENTs` are not `TRIGGERs`; they are distinctly different things in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to be corrupted files of MySQL under XAMPP. When I tried to run MySQL today on my PC, the files were corrupt and it wouldn't work until I reinstalled it. Now the event is working properly.